# Android Emulator for Tablet

Tags: android

My PC is core i-5 with 4gb RAM.

whenever i try to run an AVD in eclipse it comes fast, if i want to run an AVD for TAB it take 5 to 10 minutes. Is there any way to make it fast? Also some time it comes with blackscreen says open gl es API problem type something

Also after fast run, i dont close it, i use it same AVD for all run. But it becames slower after every installation or run by my app. so i have to close and restart my AVD, is there any solution for it. Also some time DDMS cant find AVD, while it was running in font.

Anyone face these problem? any tricks?

one another thing, some time app dont run automatically after installation, i have to select app in AVD's APPS

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making the Android emulator run faster](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster)

Comment: possible duplicate of [slow android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Comment: thanks, there accepted answer was buy fast computer, dont u think my config is enf for that?

Comment: @KishorDgupta There is no _real_ answer to your question. For example, I run the emulator on a (decent enough) osx machine and I've never come across any similar issues. Could it be Windows? Could it be your machine config? I don't know and I suspect you're not going to get a _silver bullet_ answer here.

Comment: i tried this emulator in windows xp and windows 7. I dont know why but i found it ran faster in win xp than win 7. 


thanks for ur reply. it just make development speed slow. :(

Can we run Android as OS for our PC? than it would be faster like IOS emulator :D

Comment: Just get a physical device to develop and debug on. Much more efficient.

Comment: costly suggestion, but thanks. it may be the best way

Comment: There are a lot of pixels to be shown on a tablet emulator and since the emulator is not hardware 3d accelerated it is really really low to use. Even if you create an ICS emulator, it runs really slow because it is supposed to be hardware accelerated but since the emulator is not capable, it really slows down a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Android emulator does not make use of multiple cores. Whether you have 1 or 8 cores doesn't matter. However, the speed of a single core does affect the speed of the emulator.

Having a processor with TurboBoost helps considerably, in my experience. Additionally, it is well known that the 3.X and above emulators are extremely slow by nature.

You could also try allocating more RAM to the AVD in it's setup. Reducing the screen size and resolution also helps in speeding up the emulator.

You can refer to [this Google Group thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e6db14f76b496ce1) for details on why the emulator is slow, and how to speed it up.