# Android running really slow in debug mode

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

I am trying to run an android application in debug mode in eclipse and it is really slow. How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Connect a device and debug on that directly

Comment: These threads: [(Thread 1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2662650/645270) [Thread 2)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1554099/645270) explains how to make the emulator faster.

Comment: The question doesn't say anything about using an emulator. Debugging on a device can be slow too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It usually happens in Emulator, especially when you are reading/writing files, making calls to web-server and/or the size of your .apk file increases (large apk size causes slow installation). The best solution is to use a real device which will speed-up the installation process and enhance the overall performance of your app

Answer (score 17):

Start your app without debugging and only if you have reached a point where it gets interesting for debugging, then connect your debugger using DDMS perspective -> device list -> debug process button.

Edited in 2014: Nowadays I would recommend trying the Genymotion Android virtualization. In contrast to the original Android emulator it does not emulate the core of the Android device, but instead runs it as x86 code in a virtualized system. That is typically faster. In addition it brings some features the original emulator simply does not have (like map based GPS position selection).

Comment: when app started without debugging it shows debug process button disable in ddms.

Comment: @amy Surely not. You probably did not mark your app as debuggable at all. In the AndroidManifest.xml file, add android:debuggable="true".

Comment: I marked it. I got solution I need to select process for application also

Comment: Genymotion is brilliant! Thanks for the tip, not sure how I managed to get anything done without it until now!