# Android Emulator "launcher is not responding would you like to close it?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am trying to launch my emulator on Eclipse but every time I get this message after some time of waiting

> "launcher is not responding would you like to close it ?"

anybody has an idea how to fix this problem ?

Comment: got the same problem with an API_15 emulator, with an API_16 emulator that doesn't happen though

Comment: this Kev...deleted my answer..lool. Maybe he will answer too, or just delete all what not meets his style? :)

Comment: Have you checked logcat? It may have some hints.

Comment: LogCat gives me no error

Comment: Try setting the emulator RAM a bit higher. But not more than 40% of your system RAM. And if you have a slow system, try not to multi task when emulator runs. Its pretty heavy on the system. Also try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster

Comment: You may just not be waiting long enough, especially if you're running on Windows. On some machines I've seen the emulator take several minutes to start.  During this time Windows sees it as "not responding."

Answer (score 3):

Try genymotion emulator instead of android sdk emulator.Its has very fast start up and use less ram.It is built as the alternate of android sdk emulator

Answer (score 1):

This solution works well:
1- Download&Install intel hardware accelerated execution manager from : 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager
2- From SDK Manger select and download Intel x86 System image 
[image]
3- Create a new AVD and select CPU/ABI as: intel atom x86
[image]
4- Check use host GPU 
now save and start your new AVD .

Answer (score 0):

This may be happening because your Virtual Device are trying to use resources that you don't have installed. For example, it's very likely that you have set GPU Accelreation ON ("Use host GPU checked") without having it properly configured. If you want to see how it's done, check Vika's answer to this question: [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow?rq=1)