# android: how to change CPU speed on the emulator

Tags: android, emulation, cpu

I am wondering how to change the cpu speed on the emulator so it can match with the phone specification?

If I can set to low speed, then i can see whether it works on the slower phone.

Comment: read this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster

Comment: which one do i look at ? One of them say changing the cpu used for this emulator but it only help improving the speed of the emulator.

Answer (score 3):

I am using [`cpulimit`](https://github.com/opsengine/cpulimit), a Unix program. Issuing the command

```
cpulimit -p $PID -l $CPU_SHARE
```

allots to the process with `PID` id `CPU_SHARE` percents of CPU time. The process will not use more CPU time than is allotted even when the CPU is idle. The id of the Android emulator (AVD) process can be seen with `pidof qemu-system-i386` for an x86 Android image and `pidof qemu-system-x86_64` for an x86_64 one. The program's manual can be seen with `cpulimit --help`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with [Command Line Parameters](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html#startup-options) `-cpu-delay <delay>`

Comment: "-cpu-delay" is deprecated, read https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#deprecated .