# Android emulator not installing new apk

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I recently started learning how to develop android apps. One annoyance I'm facing is that after a successful build of my code, after I modify it and make some changes and save it, the emulator won't load the new code until I close and open the emulator like 2 or 3 times. It says something along the lines of `installing blahblahblah.apk` in the console, and then after that the new code finally runs on the emulator. Until then, it keeps running the last successful build.

Does anyone know how to either:

1. Make the emulator install the new apk without requiring that I restart it several times
2. Make the emulator load faster (I already tried increasing the RAM)

I'm using the version of eclipse that came with the ADT bundle provided by Android.

Comment: Simply uninstall the app in emulator settings and run your modified code.

Comment: Android Emulator is usually slow i.e. not fast enough so you should go with a real device as it would help you to speed up development

Answer (score 1):

To make your emulator fast just do following.

download intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager. from here.
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager.

install it in  your computer.

after that intel atom system images in android SDK.

[image: install HAXM]

after that create new emulator and select intel atom in cpu option.that make ur emulator fast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
Run As > Run Configuration 
.. Android > Brows project which you want to Run.
.. Target  > Enable "Always Prompt to pick device."
.. Common  > Check both "Run & Debug".
```

And along with that `Enable (Check) Wipe User data of your virtual device` so that will uninstall older APK and install new one. Because some time emulator use older garbage reference.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing and opening the emulator(I know it is time consuming), you can

> use the "reset adb" under the devices window

to reset your emulator(it is a matter of seconds.)

Steps to speed up emulator (atleast to a small extend):

> Increase your emulator ram size. Use a small screen sized
>   emulator.(Makes the rendering process on arm faster).

Answer (score 0):

You can clear cache/data per application from settings **(Applications -> manage applications)**. This of course only clears data that your application is creating. You can also uninstall your application from there which will cause everything to be cleared. Then you can run your application without starting emulator again.

Comment: Also see this link for increasing speed upto 50%. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster

Answer (score 0):

firstly go to project->

select build automatically
if it is not working then

open the command prmt and go to the path of your sdk like-
E:\param\android-sdk\android-sdk\platform-tools
 write commnd `adb kill-server`

then again write command `adb start-server`

this will help you