# Emulator taking too long time to launch

Tags: android

Whenever I am trying to launch my emulator it launches but only the android logo is shown ,after waiting for many hrs also it does not work.

Device-3.2"QVGA(ADP2)320*480 (mdpi)
API Level-17

Comment: use [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) instead, it works faster

Comment: Check this; https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager. This makes emulator really faster then normal.

Comment: You should look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator?rq=1

Comment: I have checked it but it has to be purchased and the free version does not include important features which i want.

Comment: The intel accelerator dosen't support my laptop

Comment: Make sure you have lots of RAM.

Comment: @hrskrs not  really free ...

Answer (score 4):

It's well known that the factory emulator is extremly slow. The trick here is that the factory emulator needs to run on an ARM machine, so it needs to convert the ARM calls to your your x86 (or 64 bits) processor calls. It's likely to never run fast at all. In this situation, you may want to trust on the factory x86 images that make use of Intel's HAXM drivers, not available to everyone, and I couldn't manage to make it work myself, but it's useful to know that.

**However!** Since a while ago, I started using Genymotion's emulators. They rely on an actual virtual machine, which is way way faster than anything a factory emulator could achieve. Even if I'm running it on the lowest Mac Mini out there, it's pretty smooth. I'd personally give it a try (well, precisely, I gave a try)

https://www.genymotion.com/

Comment: but what do they even mean by 5 usd cents per minute

Answer (score 2):

Try allocating more memory for it to use.  The Android Emulator is super slow as it is, but if you are not giving it enough memory it has the ability to never load.

Answer (score 1):

Google emulator uses ARM opcode, a kind of machine language. It must convert from ARM opcode to Intel opcode. That's why it's slow. The problem seems not to be RAM but CPU. Improving CPU will improve the emulator.

References to solve this issue:

[Making the Android emulator run faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your emulator in windows than you can use Microsoft Andriod Emulator.

[Install microsoft android emulator in your windows os](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/msft-android-emulator-vs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If it is taking too much time in loading make sure you have installed the "**HAXM installer**" in SDK tools , Also make sure "**Hyper V**" option is also unchecked in "**Turn Windows features on or off**" in **Control Panel** --> **Program and features**.

Only After unchecking this feature you can install the HAXM installer.

After doing this the Emulator will not take time to load.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the Android virtual device with more RAM than usual. The usual is 1 GB. Even though I tried this on another lower end PC, it was still slow. I think it can be a problem with your hardware. Lower end hardware tends to have problems running emulators.

Answer (score -1):

The problem seems not to be RAM but CPU. Improving CPU will improve the emulator.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).