# Meteor mobile development

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, meteor

I am building a mobile app in meteor. But the development is very slow. I am using simulator. But working with Simulator slows the development a lot. Making change in the code does not refresh the app quickly, it delays a lot. Like, it takes longer if I connect to the real phone.

I am wondering is there any way to develop meteor app in mobile quickly?
I wanna speed up the development process.

I am using android. And the commands that I am using are

```
meteor run android //to run in simulator
meteor run android-device// to run in mobile
```

Comment: Refer to this link  , 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster

Answer (score 0):

Try use [genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) simulator. It is as fast as a real device IMO. Try it. Should work.

Comment: can it be used for meteor and have u tried it with meteor?

Comment: No I haven't try it with meteor and I don't have experience with it,  but  genymotion acts like a normal android-device give it a try with `meteor run android-device` command