# Android Emulator seems to be running slow, correct settings?

Tags: android, android-emulator, appium, appium-android

Android Emulator seems to be running slow, correct settings?

I have configured many settings and have created multiple instances of android emulator(s), when the emulator loads and when i press the power button the phone seems to take ages to load the background, phone functionality etc.

Emulator setup 1/2:
[image]

Emulator setup 2/2:
[image]

My System:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The selected image is `ARM Android 7.1.1 armeabi-v7a`. That's why. Try to use `x86` or `x86-64` images as much as possible, they are MUCH faster. Also, make sure your computer has virtualization enabled (sometimes you need to enable it in the BIOS/UEFI), and that you're using Intel HAXM (see the [official documentation for more details](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html)).

In your particular case, AMD processor on Windows, seems that [virtualization acceleration will not be possible](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration.html#accel-vm):

> Virtualization extension requirements
>
> Before attempting to use acceleration, you should first determine if your CPU supports one of the following virtualization extensions technologies:
>
> - Intel Virtualization Technology (VT, VT-x, vmx) extensions
> - AMD Virtualization (AMD-V, SVM) extensions (**Linux only**)

Anyway, by using an `x86` or `x86-64` emulation should be already noticeably faster.

Comment: thanks would it still be possible if i have an AMD processor?

Comment: Apparently, the virtualization part is not available for AMD on Windows. I'll update the answer.

Comment: thanks, so in my case with my machine what option would be most suited to me?

Comment: Create a new emulator device (AVD) using any of the `x86` or `x86-64` images available (which BTW are the ones that Google recommends when creating a new image). Virtualization acceleration will give a extra boost, but you cannot make use of it.

Comment: thanks again, so this will defenitaly work with my AMD processor?

Comment: You're creating a new image for your emulator, without removing the old one. So, yes, it will work. And the worst thing that could happen is that the new image doesn't work, so you could keep using the old, slow image.

Comment: thanks i will give it a try and provide you with an update

Comment: @xGIx did it work for you? Did the emulator speed improve?

Comment: sorry for the late reply i tried the following: 'ou're creating a new image for your emulator, without removing the old one. So, yes, it will work' but i was still receiving the existing message and wasnt able to run the emulator, any ideas?

Comment: You need to create a new virtual device. This is from AVD ("Your Virtual Devices" in AS), using the "+ Create Virtual Device..." button at lower left corner.

Comment: thanks, I will check when i get some time, so performing the following will enable me to assign a quicker processor to my setup all though i have an AMD processor on my machine?

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view and in comparison with my own configuration, everything seems pretty normal, but I have some tips regarding current configuration only (optimization will come after).

I notice you are emulating the front AND back cameras. If you're not effectively using any with the app you're developing, I would consider turning it off and not emulate them, and if you are using cameras, maybe just emulate one, it will be faster. Also, maybe increasing the VM heap would help.

For more powerful optimization using things other than just the configuration you posted, please refer to this post : [Making the Android emulator run faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster)