# "Making the Android emulator run faster" explanation of answer

Tags: android, ubuntu-16.04, emulation, android-virtual-device

in the post
[Making the Android emulator run faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662650/making-the-android-emulator-run-faster)

there is the answer:

**Linux:**

- Install KVM: open GOOGLE, write "kvm installation "
- Create AVD with "Intel atom x86" CPU/ABI
- Run from command line: emulator -avd
  avd_name -qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm
- Or run from Eclipse: Run/Run
  Configurations/Tab "Target" - > check Intel x86 AVD and in
  "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" window add: -qemu -m 512
  -enable-kvm (click Run)

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (and Oracle VM virtual box and Genymotion - but do not know if it matters there), I probably sucessfully installed KVM. Although, I do not understand the next part:

Create AVD with "Intel atom x86" CPU/ABI

What program or command this is?

Comment: follow the instructions here: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installing-the-intel-atom-x86-system-image-for-android-emulator-add-on-from-the-android-sdk-manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVD means Android Virtual Device. They most likely mean the that you use the normal emulator in Android Studio.

Here's a link that [describes the process](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds)

Basically you have several AVD images to pick from, and you have to pick one that has an x86 CPU as opposed to an ARM CPU in the ABI column.