# Run android emulator faster - nexus 4 configuration

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation

I found some ideas how to run android emulator faster, but for Nexus 4 configuration still it doesn't work correctly.

My PC: 
AMD Phenom II X4 955 (4 x 3,20Ghz)
4 GB ram memory
ATI 5750
Windows 7 64bit

Virtual Device Configuration:
Name: Nexus 4 ;)
Device: 4.65" 720p (720 x 1280: xhdpi)
Target: Android 4.2.2
Skin: Display a skin with hardware control - checked
RAM: 756 
VM Heap: 64
Internal Storage: 200MiB

PC is very fast updated but without SP1 - because after SP1 some games and application were working slower for me then before SP1.

So, main issue is: emulator works all the time with 'lag'. 
For ex: I clicked 'menu' button and then I was waiting 3s to see list of apps. 
And everything on emulator is working like this. It is very tiring to make good tests.

Do you have some ideas how can I improve it?

Best Mob86.

Answer (score 2):

The emulator runs at a usable speed with top end machines, but has a slight delay on older ones. There is no need to run the AVD on a Virtual Machine. But it seems to be faster that way. The emulator takes long to startup but you don't have to close it after testing, the reason for this is it is starting up the android OS, much like booting windows.

What you can do?

- Disable boot animation (speeds up boot time)
- Use Host GPU (use with nvidia cards, renders with your GPU)
- Snapshot (boots up from snapshot of previous boot)

Further info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968170/can-i-tweak-my-android-emulator-to-make-it-fast).

Comment: Good answer,  also look at using the other images that use HAX which run a lot faster,  depending on your hardware and without the Google apis.

Comment: This link could also be useful if you want to use an alternative to the AVD: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/05/debug-android-app-to-bluestacks-app.html

Answer (score 0):

I am using: http://www.genymotion.com/ this is virtual android device based on `VirtualBox` and run faster than nexus 4.

Answer (score 0):

Start the emulator using this cmd line

**emulator -no-boot-anim @your_emulator**

It reduce 50% boot time..