# Hello Android problem

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying the VERY basic tutorial for Android and can't seem to get it to work correctly. Here is a link to an image of what happens when I run the app. It should say Hello Android but it doesn't. I feel retarded.

http://teewebco.com/images/helloandroid.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem. [my thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966393/android-emulator-alternative). The emulator is slow. What you're seeing is the boot screen. Try leaving it for 10-20 mins and see if it boots up. Or, even better, if you have an Android device, plug it in and run it on that. General advice is that once it's up and running, don't turn it off. You can carry on coding while it's still on and it will update.

Comment: Wow..fast response. Why is it so slow?

Comment: I'm new to Android as well, so maybe someone else knows the intricacies. However, from what I gather, it emulates the entire operating system, so it's bound to be quite slow. It's also running on non-native hardware, so it can't always take advantage of hardware speeds in certain procedures. Hopefully they manage to tweak it to increase speed in an update.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the link to my thread in my post. It's fixed now.